# How get only one result for each company in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have query but now I need to change the query to the database to get only one result for each company in the table `Price`.

For this I add row `GROUP by p.id_firm` and than I get next query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
  p.id_price as p_id_price, 
  p.id_service as p_id_service, 
  p.name as p_name, 
  p.name_original as p_name_original, 
  p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country, 
  p.id_firm as p_id_firm, 
  f.name as f_name, 
  f.address as f_address, 
  f.phone as f_phone, 
  city.name as city_name, 
  pc.name as pc_name 
FROM Price p 
left join Firm f 
  on f.id_service=p.id_service 
  AND f.id_city=p.id_city 
  AND f.id_firm=p.id_firm 
left join City city 
  on city.id_city = p.id_city 
left join Producer_country pc 
  on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
WHERE p.id_city='73041' 
  AND p.include='1' 
  AND p.blocked='0' 
  AND f.blocked='0' 
  AND ( f.name LIKE 'Окно%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS OR p.name LIKE 'Окно%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS ) 
GROUP by p.id_firm ORDER BY p.name ASC
```

But if I use it, I get error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'Price.id_price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

*Tell me please the right way to change this query or maybe make other?*

**Structure all tables you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fad4d1)**

P.S.: Sorry for the inaccuracy. Search by firm name and the name product . If the search term is contained in the product name or the name of the company, and there are some of the results with the same id_firm, need choose one the most suitable value, that is id_firm in results search should be unique.

Comment: Which relations are there between tables?

Comment: Refere this example [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680254/t-sql-selecting-column-based-on-maxother-column

Comment: Well, if one firm has multiple people / services / prices, which one do you want? And you can't say "it doesn't matter" because SQL Server needs to know.

Comment: @helloSuresh: In comments, only the `[text](link)` template is supported for link formatting. See [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more info.

Comment: I don't see any aggregates in the query, am I missing them? If not, why are you using GROUP? Maybe you just want ORDER BY?

Comment: @AaronBertrand table prices have products name, id_firm and other inputs. If i make query i get all results, but me need get all results but only 1 result with one id_firm(id_firm in all resuts will be unique).

Comment: @LeoLoki you still need to be *specific*. If a firm has two products, ***WHICH*** product do you want?

Comment: @AaronBertrand sorry for the inaccuracy. Search by firm name and the name product . If the search term is contained in the product name or the name of the company, and there are some of the results with the same id_firm, need choose one the most suitable value, that is id_firm in results search should be unique.

Comment: As an aside note, your `f.blocked='0'` condition in `WHERE` essentially transforms your `left join Firm` into `inner join Firm`, because it filters out join results where there is no match between `Price` and `Firm`. (If, however, `Price` *always* has a match in `Firm` then why do you use `left join` instead of `inner join`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) instead of grouping.

Number every company's rows separately. When sorting the rows for `ROW_NUMBER()`, use the `p.name LIKE 'Окно%'` condition to put rows with matching products before the others.

Here's an example what it might look like:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    p.id_price as p_id_price, 
    p.id_service as p_id_service, 
    p.name as p_name, 
    p.name_original as p_name_original, 
    p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country, 
    p.id_firm as p_id_firm, 
    f.name as f_name, 
    f.address as f_address, 
    f.phone as f_phone, 
    city.name as city_name, 
    pc.name as pc_name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY p.id_firm
      ORDER BY
        CASE  -- this criterion puts matching products before non-matching ones
          WHEN p.name LIKE 'Окно%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
          THEN 1 ELSE 2
        END,
        p.id_price  -- you may use any sorting criteria at this point,
                    -- just ensure it makes the results predictable
    ) AS rnk
  FROM Price p 
  left join Firm f 
    on f.id_service=p.id_service 
    AND f.id_city=p.id_city 
    AND f.id_firm=p.id_firm 
  left join City city 
    on city.id_city = p.id_city 
  left join Producer_country pc 
    on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
  WHERE p.id_city='73041' 
    AND p.include='1' 
    AND p.blocked='0' 
    AND f.blocked='0' 
    AND ( f.name LIKE 'Окно%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
       OR p.name LIKE 'Окно%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS ) 
)
SELECT TOP 20
  p_id_price, 
  p_id_service, 
  p_name, 
  p_name_original, 
  p_id_producer_country, 
  p_id_firm, 
  f_name, 
  f_address, 
  f_phone, 
  city_name, 
  pc_name
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
-- the absence of ORDER BY makes your TOP 20 results indeterminate
;
```

Basically, this ranks every company's rows, then pulls only the rows with the rankings of `1` from all the companies, making it ultimately one row per company.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Select Distinct for a possible quick fix
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp